# How to use xmodmap to use Alt Key as a Shift Key?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I want to use my left alt key as a shift key, but my attempts at remapping have failed. Using the following .Xmodmap file(I have taken the Hex Codes from my `keysymdef.h` to eliminate this possible error source):

```
!0xffe9 = Alt_L
remove mod1 = 0xffe9
!0xffe1 = Shift_L
keycode 64 = 0xffe1
add shift = 0xffe1
```

And running

```
xmodmap ./.Xmodmap
```

works fine. When I run `xev` and press my left alt key I get:

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x2af, subw 0x0, time 136342090, (2225,316), root:(2253,374),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 50
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

which seems right. Running `xmodmap -p` also gives me seemingly good output:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e),  Shift_L (0x40)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Still, I can not use my alt key for shifting letters. It still works just like before. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm not sure why. Other commands work fine, for example `xmodmap -e "keycode 38 = 0x33"` correctly remaps my "a" key to "3".

Comment: `xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Alt_L"`
`xmodmap -e "add shift = Alt_L"` - is it what you want?

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. Running `xev` gave me the output that my left alt key was still being used an alt key. Did this work on your machine?

Comment: yes, it works, I just didn't try it very much because I need left Alt as usual

Comment: That's interesting, so it might be a problem specific to my machine. Would you mind telling me what kind of Operating system you are using?

Comment: It's Ubuntu Mate 20 in my case. What is the output of xmodmap then?

Comment: I haven't tried it out yet, but I'm gonna upgrade to Ubuntu 20 in the coming days, hopefully that fixes the problem. Gonna let you know as soon as that is done. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to KUbuntu 20.04, running the same commands work now as expected. The problem might be with Ubuntu 18, it could also have been caused from some broken packages that I held.